# Angular service not working with http.get observable

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I am trying to retrieve json file from the server using http.get and subscribe to the observable from a component. However, it's returning an error, not the data.

Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MoviesService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getMovies() : Observable<any> {
    let url = API_URL;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

and here's the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from './movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css'],
  providers: [
    MoviesService
  ]
})

export class MoviesComponent {

  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) {};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moviesService.getMovies().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log("Success " + data);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using latest versions of Angular and rxjs library.

Please help.

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console. Open Dev Tools in your Browesr, Navigate to the Network Tab, Click Filter and see the XHR section to see the request and check if it responded successfully.

Comment: If my answer didn't solve you issue, consider creating a StackBlitz Demo so that someone could have a look into it. You can create one here: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Please see the link https://movies-api-ng.stackblitz.io

Comment: The API that you're using is not secure. Try using a secure API to get the movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HttpClient instead of `Http`. `Http` returns an Object of type `Response`. You'll have to call the `json()` method on it which will give you the data that you're looking for.

To avoid doing that, use `HttpClient`. And to use `HttpClient`, you'll have to first add `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your module.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MoviesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getMovies() : Observable<any> {
    let url = API_URL;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

### Update

Your API isn't secure. That's why the client is blocking it and giving a mixed content error. This generally happens when some of your content is served over HTTPS and some are served over HTTP. I don't really think there's a way to fix this without changing the API.

You should consider using an secure API for movies.

You can use [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com/). It's a Secure and Free API to get movie details. You'll have to create an API Key first. You can do that [here](http://www.omdbapi.com/apikey.aspx).

Comment: I'm using angular 6. It cannot find @angular/common/http. Could only import Http from @angular/http

Comment: please check the editor url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/movies-api-ng

Comment: Insecure API call was the problem. Thank you very much for helping out. I've hosted the API on GitHub and it worked. I'm restricted to use the same API data in my test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had both HttpClientTestingModule and HttpClientModule in the imports section of my app.module.ts file.

Removing the HttpClientTestingModule from the app.module.ts fixed my issue.

Angular: 11.0.9

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| @angular-devkit/architect | 0.1100.7 |
| @angular-devkit/build-angular | 0.1100.7 |
| @angular-devkit/core | 11.0.7 |
| @angular-devkit/schematics | 11.0.7 |
| @angular/cdk | 11.2.5 |
| @angular/cli | 11.0.7 |
| @angular/material | 11.2.5 |
| @schematics/angular | 11.0.7 |
| @schematics/update | 0.1100.7 |
| rxjs | 6.6.6 |
| typescript | 4.0.7 |