# Loading Failed for the module with source

Tags: javascript, angular, github, hosting, github-pages

I tried to host my website via Github Pages but the page shows nothing and in the console, it shows errors.

Page URL: https://oneofthedevs.github.io/website/

Github Repo URL: https://github.com/oneofthedevs/website

I have tried rebuilding the application

Blocked loading mixed active content “http://oneofthedevs.github.io/website/styles.6ecb5fbf463a75da71fd.css”

Loading failed for the module with source “http://oneofthedevs.github.io/website/runtime-es2015.703a23e48ad83c851e49.js”.

and other errors with same message

Comment: Check the [`Updated`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136831/angular-service-not-working-with-http-get-observable/52136870#52136870) section of this answer. You seem to be loading css on HTTP while your App loads on HTTPS. Hence the error.